# C++ template function to concatenate both std::vector and std::array types

Tags: c++, templates, stl, stdvector, stdarray

I have project where I am working with both fixed and variable length arrays of bytes. I want to have a function that can concatenate two arbitrary containers of bytes and return a single vector. Currently I am using

```
std::vector<uint8_t> catBytes(uint8_t const* bytes1, size_t const len1, 
                              uint8_t const* bytes2, size_t const len2) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> all_bytes;
    all_bytes.reserve(len1 + len2);
    all_bytes.insert(all_bytes.begin(), bytes1, bytes1 + len1);
    all_bytes.insert(all_bytes.begin() + len1, bytes2, bytes2 + len2);
    return all_bytes;
} // catBytes
```

However, I would like more generic way to do this, which better uses the capabilities of C++. I do not want to just accept iterators. I am trying to figure out how to accept two arbitrary containers and return a vector containing their contents. Ideally I would also not like to have to know the type inside the vector.

Something like

```
std::vector<unit_8> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::array<unit_8, 4> a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::array<unit_8, 2> a2 = { 1, 2 };
auto res1 = concat(v1, a1); // std::vector<uint_8> of size 8
auto res2 = concat(a1, a2); // std::vector<uint_8> of size 6

// or

std::vector<char> v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::array<char, 4> a3 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto res3 = concat(v1, a1); // std::vector<char> of size 8
```

I think there is a templated approach to this but I just have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, generic + arbitrary, means templates.

Something like this?

```cpp
template<class SizedRange1, class SizedRange2>
auto concat(SizedRange1 const& r1, SizedRange2 const& r2) {
    std::vector<typename SizedRange1::value_type> ret;
    ret.reserve(r1.size() + r2.size());

    using std::begin; using std::end;
    ret.insert(ret.end(), begin(r1), end(r1));
    ret.insert(ret.end(), begin(r2), end(r2));

    return ret;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

The advantage of @康桓瑋's solution (which assumes that you are only interested in concatenating contiguous memory containers as you stated) is that you have a *single* function and you avoid code bloat.

As you noticed in the comments, the problem with that you can not deduce the element type, which can be anything in principle, so you are back to needing templates anyway.

Fortunately, you can combine the two approaches and reduce the number of functions generated as machine code, in the case that you have many different input containers, which is combinatorial.

```cpp
template<class T>
std::vector<T> 
concat_aux(std::span<const T> x, std::span<const T> y) {
  std::vector<T> ret;
  ret.reserve(x.size() + y.size());
  ret.insert(ret.end(), x.begin(), x.end());
  ret.insert(ret.end(), y.begin(), y.end());
  return ret;
}

template<class ContinuousRange1, class ContinuousRange2>
auto concat(ContinuousRange1 const& r1, ContinuousRange2 const& r2) {
  return concat_aux<typename ContinousRange1::value_type>(r1, r2);
}
```

The advantage is marginal here, but if the function `concat` is very complicated this last approach will pay off because it will generate code only for the different types of elements, not the number of containers squared in your instantiating code.

Comment: This worked perfectly. The `auto` return type I didn't know was possible. Also the `typename ...` helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

`std::array`, `std::vector` and other `contiguous_ranges` can be converted to a lightweight [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span), which you can use for type erasure.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

std::vector<uint8_t> 
catBytes(std::span<const uint8_t> x, std::span<const uint8_t> y) {
  std::vector<uint8_t> all_bytes;
  all_bytes.reserve(x.size() + y.size());
  all_bytes.insert(all_bytes.begin(), x.begin(), x.end());
  all_bytes.insert(all_bytes.end(), y.begin(), y.end());
  return all_bytes;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/64fsj6dhW)

Comment: Thank you, I really like the use of `std::span` here. I noticed that it will cast things to `uint8_t` though. Is there a way to make that generic so the function will work with spans of `int`, `char`, etc. without casting?

Comment: @nalyd88 if you add a template parameter to span you can’t deduce it unfortunately when passing vectors and arrays. something intermediate between this and the other answer may work. but it is a lot of work for what it is worth. if you need to be generic in the element type you might just use the other solution.

Comment: Thank, you. The `span` turned out to be really useful as well. Wish I could accept both answers since I benefited from both!

Comment: @nalyd88 you can combine both methods to minimize code generation at a minimal runtime cost (e.g. copying pointers). See my edit.